# Freeswitch - mod_spandsp: Cannot send non-existant fax file

Tags: freeswitch

I just recently set up a FOIP server which involved configuring several different applications and one of them is freeswitch. I've searched and searched but haven't found a good solution for this problem, so I'll get right to it. This is the error message:

```
[ERR] mod_spanddsp_fax.c:1367 Cannot send non-existant fax file [usr/ictcore/data/document/document_1.tiff]
```

I have tired several things to troubleshoot the issue such as checking permissions, installing the correct dependencies, etc...so if that error message strikes anyone as something familiar please share. I can provide full logs per request.

Comment: I think you trying to set up ictfax server.
It's not a permission issue. try `locate document_1.tiff` in your FOIP server terminal screen and see where its located. Its expecting to reside in `usr/ictcore/data/document/`

Comment: That's correct I'm setting up an ictfax server. Based on my searches, stuff related to permission issues turned up a few times, so I thought I'd share. Problem is that those files don't exist. I'm very new to freeswitch, but if my understanding is correct, mod_spandsp creates the files on the fly (or at least mod_spandsp calls on other programs to create the file). I don't know how well versed you are with ictfax, but if I create the tiff file manually, I don't get an error message, but creating the file manually which involves using ghostcript doesn't work from an enduser perspective

Comment: ictfax use a web interface where you can upload pdf and image file which then converts to tiff file so spandsp can send it to siptrunk provider. If you want this for internal users purpose you can stick to ictfax. Other wise standalone freeswitch is your best choice. Take a look at `http://demo.ictfax.org/`. `mod_spandsp` doesn't do any doc conversion. I've tried ictfax only once to see how it uses freeswitch to send fax. Solution to your's is upload a pdf doc in ictfax web page -- outbound fax-create new-. after that try to locate that document name with .tiff in your terminal.

Comment: I haven't thought of uploading a pdf file then trying to locate the converted tiff file before sending the fax, so that's something I can try out. Up till now, I would create a new fax, attached a pdf, then look at freeswitch logs for debugging. Always get that same error message. Just out of curiosity, why do you think it's not a permissions issue?

Comment: Error clearly says `non-existant` it not about, `cannot open`

Comment: Thanks for the tips. That non-existant error is clearly confusing. But, I found the "bug" if you want to call it that, that was causing my problem. Here's a hint for people who run into this stupid issue. Disable SElinux before changing any configuration files and make the changes permanent, otherwise a reboot will put you back right where you started.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint for people who run into this stupid issue. Disable SElinux before changing any configuration files and make the changes permanent, otherwise a reboot will put you back right where you started.